# Ajax POST doesn't work with Flask / IIS7.5

Tags: python, jquery, post, flask, iis-7.5

Because I start to go crazy I really need your help xD
I'm tying to make a simple Ajax POST, and with it I want to send JSON data to python script to save it later on server.
I'm using python 3.6.4 (anaconda3 with wfastcgi.py) for backend and Javascript (jQuery) and Flask for frontend.

Here's what I got from Chrome Dev Tools -> Network:

[image]

`POST 1` is from local python server Werkzeug, `POST 2` is from IIS 7.5.
I'm showing both in hope that it will help locate the problem. I only need a way to fix IIS.

I already tried :
`<customHeaders>` with Access-Control-Allow-Origin etc
`<requestFiltering>` with `<add verb="POST" allowed="true" />`, or `<verbs allowUnlisted="true">`
changing `OPTIONSVerbHandler` verb from OPTIONS to POST (don't ask me, found it here)
But it didn't help.

With `Failed Request Tracing Rules` module I was able to find this:

[image]

But I don't know what where in IIS I can change anything with FastCgi to make it work with POST.

My Ajax POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/static/scripts/saveData.py",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(tableObject),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
```

});

ps. Link to file works because when I change POST to GET I get code from saveData.py in `console.log(response)`.

Comment: CORS headers should be configured via IIS CORS module, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: Done that, didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo, after close to 2 days of looking in net, tying different ways to make it work, i finally found a way to send a Ajax POST.

Basically I had to change target url `"/static/scripts/saveData.py"` from local address to Flask url `"/annotate"` and this enable me to send data with POST and letter process it in views.py (my main flask view file).

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/annotate",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(tableObject),
        //data: tableObject,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```

Now, why this work, and POST to normal .py script doesn't, I don't know.
But at least now I can work with that data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to register this method in flask routs:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

Comment: I have `methods=['GET', 'POST']` in page were this POST is called